# Calculate radius - a typical problem

Tags: geometry

If in3 circles each circle intersects each of the other two on one point each . If radius of 1 circle is 3cm and other circle is 5cm, find radius of 3rd.

Answer (score 5):

Your question has more than one answer. In the image below, you see one circle with radius $r_1$ and one with $r_2$ (the two black circles). Simply knowing that the third circle touches each of the other two in exactly one point is not enough to tell me how large the third circle is. It can be small (red circle) or large (orange circle).

[image]

Comment: the red one you might take

Comment: @lostinspaces You missed the point. From what you described, there are infinitely many circles I can draw.

Comment: question is correct

Comment: @lostinspaces The question, as you wrote it, cannot be answered. Simple as that. My answer clearly demonstrates that.

Comment: @lostinspaces: There are even more families of solutions than 5xum's diagram illustrates.  The question lacks sufficient detail to be answered.